# 'Owin.IAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'MapSignalR'

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, owin

#### Error

> 'Owin.IAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'MapSignalR' and
> no extension method 'MapSignalR' accepting a first argument of type
> 'Owin.IAppBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive
> or an assembly reference?)

#### Code

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRChat.Startup))]
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

#### Update

signalR version 2.0.3
Microsoft Owin version 2.0.2
Owin version 1.0.0
Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Only install this nuget:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost
```

Comment: Need to install this [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Cors/) too:

    Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Cors -Version 3.1.0

Answer (score 26):

Finally was able to solve it by adding ***signalR*** dependencies before adding signalR from NuGet Packages
Step's I followed:

1. Added Microsoft.Owin `//version 2.0.1`
2. Added Microsoft.Owin.Security `//version 2.0.1`
3. Added Microsoft Asp.Net SignalR

The reason I discovered was a problem with `version 2.0.2` of *Microsoft.Owin and Microsoft.Owin.Security* and then adding a class named ***`Startup.cs`*** with following code:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(webApp.Startup))]
namespace webApp
{
    public static class Startup
    {
        public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Directly adding `Microsoft Asp.Net SignalR` from NuGet adds `version 2.0.2 of Microsoft.Owin and Microsoft.Owin.Security` which creates the problem.
Hope it helps someone...!!

Comment: Thanks! You saved me from getting very frustrated on a Friday night!

Comment: FYI as of 2/15/2015 this seems to have been resolved.  I only installed Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR directly and the above worked fine.

Comment: This is an old solution. Do refer the answer by @mggSoft for the latest answer.

Comment: Thank you so much my friend... your solution solved my problem which I was working for 1 hours...

Answer (score 14):

```
Update-Package Owin -Reinstall
```

worked for me

Comment: Worked for me too thank you.  I tried the other solutions above and they did not work.  This one did.

Answer (score 4):

Install Nuget Package: `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin`

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem. Turns out my .csproj file the first line:

Project ToolsVersion="12.0" didn't match my other files. Changed it to:

Project ToolsVersion="14.0"

and no more compile issue.

Answer (score 3):

Using MVC5, enter your Startup.cs file.

Add `IAppBuilder appBuilder` to `Configure()`:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
```

Then, under

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

add `appBuilder.MapSignalR();`

Answer (score 1):

Asp.Net 5 empty mvc project out of the box creates something that looks like this

```
 using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
namespace DeadlyChat
{
public class Startup
{
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();



       }
    }
}
```

Took me a while to notice that Configure was supposed to be Configuration and IApplicationBuilder needs to be IAppBuilder. I also pulled off the assembly annotation above the namespace.

I wound up scrapping trying to use Asp.Net 5 couldn't get it to work. Went back to 4.6 and everything worked fine. Followed this walkthrough http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr