# app.MapSignalR is not a member of IAppBuilder

Tags: c#, signalr, owin, class-library

I'm getting this error when trying to map SignalR in my Startup.cs class shown below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyControl.Webserver.Startup))]
namespace MyControl.Webserver
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

I have read the other question that's asking the same question ['Owin.IAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'MapSignalR'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057459/owin-iappbuilder-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-mapsignalr). Only difference being that NuGet has correctly installed Added Microsoft.Owin version 2.0.1 and Added Microsoft.Owin.Security version 2.0.1.

I've tried creating another class library just the same. Installing Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR from NuGet and adding the same Startup.cs class. Then it works.

I'm using:

- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR 2.1.1
- Microsoft.Owin 2.0.1
- Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.0.1
- Owin 1.0

I have no idea where to go from here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by deleting some files stashed away in another folder.

They didn't seem to be referenced anywhere, but they must have been doing something :-)