# Owin.IAppBuilder does not contain a definition for 'MapSignalR' error in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, signalr, owin

I am getting this error

> Owin.IAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'MapSignalR' and
>   no extension   method 'MapSignalR' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Owin.IAppBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

This is my code

```
 using System;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using Microsoft.Owin;
 using Owin;

 [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(VirtualClassroom.Startup1))]

 namespace VirtualClassroom
 {
     public class Startup1
        {
           public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
               {
                    app.MapSignalR();

               }
        }
```

}
I searched a lot and tried as per stack overflow answer
   ['Owin.IAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'MapSignalR'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057459/owin-iappbuilder-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-mapsignalr) I had

1.Added Microsoft.Owin //version 2.0.1

2.Added Microsoft.Owin.Security //version 2.0.1

3.Added Microsoft Asp.Net SignalR

But still I am getting the same error. Please help. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: which version of `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll` do you have?

Comment: I am having SignalR 2.0.1 .I was having the latest version but according to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801385/owin-iappbuilder-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-mapsignalr-error-in-asp-net  I uninstalled the latest version and installed signalR 2.0.1 @christiandev

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you have an old version of `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll`, go to nuGet and install this package and you should see this extension method...
[image]

You should then see a bunch of these methods `public static IAppBuilder MapSignalR(this IAppBuilder builder);` under `OwinExtensions`.

**EDIT**: Based on comment

Go to references, and click on properties of this reference...

[image]

The **version** should be similar to below...

[image]

Comment: Do I need to uninstall all the signalR components and owin components before installing this? @christiandev

Comment: if you do this using nuGet package manager, it will take care of the dependencies for you.  If you look in the right of the screenshot, you can see it has a *Dependencies* section.

Comment: I tried installing using nuGet still I am getting the same error @christiandev

Comment: For me its showing like Version  1.0.0.0 (The version in last row) What I am supposed to do @christiandev

Comment: Did you update via nuget? or was it not listed in your *installed packages*? if not, delete that reference and add via NuGet.

Comment: I added via NuGet only sir. Tools->Nuget packages->manage Nuget packages and I installed the package @christiandev

Comment: Does your path point to a *packages* folder? go to that folder and check if there's a newer version there.  You have an outdated version.

Comment: How to update to the latest version?Its actually in bin folder and I actually copied all the dll files from old project bin folder to this bin folder.I think Its causing the problem.How to update to latest dll? @christiandev

Comment: Delete it from the reference, and re-add via nuget.  Avoid copying from one bin to another.

Comment: I deleted from reference but still its showing like installed when I try to add via nuGet @christiandev

Comment: Only the reference @christiandev

Comment: If it's in the installed packages, click uninstall and then reinstall, maybe.  Either way, the issue is the lack of correct version.  SO don't really appreciate chat in comments, and your points are too low to open a chat discussion.

Comment: I resolved that error but another error arose in this              public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected()
        {
            var item = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId);
            if (item != null)
            {
                ConnectedUsers.Remove(item);

                var id = Context.ConnectionId;
                Clients.All.onUserDisconnected(id, item.UserName);

            }

            return base.OnDisconnected();
        }
This is the error "No overload for method Ondisconnected" @christiandev

Comment: @Anusha, post the full question as a new question and I will take a look.